# Rendering HTML markup on client

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have saved markup in SQL Server via a rich text editor - http://hackerwins.github.io/summernote/

So in my case I just saved an header markup like: `<h1>Header content</h1>` and then tracking it back to view page like:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.businessDetails)
```

Model:

```
[AllowHtml]
public string businessDetails { get; set; }
```

This renders the view same as saved with markup in database.

```
<h1>Header content</h1>
```

How do I show formatted content without markup on client side?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the `Html.Raw` method to turn off the automatic HTML encoding:

```
@Html.Raw(Model.businessDetails)
```